# How to crop an image in Scribus?

Tags: scribus

Is it possible to crop an image in an imageframe?

It's the first time I am using scribus, so this might be a dumb question, but adjusting layer to image and vice versa was immediately clear, but cropping just wasn't and google didn't yield me any usefull results just yet..

Of course I know cropping isn't the first duty of a dtp program like Scribus, but it looked simple enough to expect it.

Answer (score 9):

Oh dear! It waited here for so long! I hope it still helps.

Select “Image Frame” with content you want to crop. In “Properties” window (usually F2/Window->Properties) go to the “Image” section. There you can select between two modes: “Free Scaling” and “Scale To Frame Size”. They're quite self-explanatory: the latter will scale your content along with Image Frame, the former will make image “immune” to changes of its container size, thus enabling you to effectively “crop” image.

Comment: Cropping this way in Scribus does not change the image which is referenced. This has got advantages and disadvantages, depending on your work-flow. If I need smaller files (for sending somewhere) I visually do all the "cropping" in Scribus within the context of the entire page. Then I take notes about size and position. Then I go back to GIMP to do a "real crop" and then tell Scribus about the new version of my image. More work but smaller files and even faster printing / exporting in certain situations.

Comment: @MartinZaske That kind of patience is commendable. Incidentally I stumbled upon a script (https://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Image_crop,_resize_and_CMYK_conversion._Save_and_reload_in_TIFF_format) which promises to do almost exactly what you are doing but in a more convenient and faster way. Have you, by any chance, tried this one?

Comment: @MartinZaske Oh, and about not changing the source image: it's fully intentional on my behalf. It has a lot to do with my workflow in which the only thing I have to send to somebody is a PDF file. In that case I prefer maximum flexibility at any stage of design over optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click -> Edit image... will open the file in your default image editor.
Be aware that you are editing the original image this way.

Comment: This is not as good as cropping within Scribus because you will have a harder time un-cropping later if you so desire. The answer from thebodzio is better because it is non-destructive editing.

Answer (score 1):

What I managed to do was this, considering that I only had to crop the image in one direction:

1. Add the image frame (Insert -> Image Frame or <kbd>I</kbd>) with and resize it so that the size of the image you want to use as scaling constraint (non-cropping direction) is what you want. Make the size in the other direction bigger. You can do this precisely in Properties <kbd>F2</kbd> -> X, Y, Z, options "width" or "height".
2. Once the constraining size is defined, select the image for the frame with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.
3. Right-click the image frame and select "Adjust Image to Frame".
4. Right-click again and select "Content Properties" (or use <kbd>F3</kbd>).
5. Change the "Scale" option from "To Frame Size" to "Free Scaling" and close the dialog.
   [image: Content Properties dialog]
6. Now you can resize the image frame (either visually with the mouse or the Properties pane) and the image will be cropped.

**Notes:**

1. If you ended cropping but think the image is a little off and should be moved inside the image box, you can double-click it and Scribus will change the mode, allowing you to directly move the image without having to change the frame around.
2. The size of the image inside the frame can be tweaked in the Content Properties (<kbd>F3</kbd>) dialog.
3. The "Content Properties" actually opens an "Image Properties" window. I called it dialog, but it is actually a dockable window/pane. You can move it to the side and change other stuff in the UI while the pane is open.
4. This procedure can be easily used for cropping in two directions, precisely or not. After changing to "Free Scaling", the image scaling inside the frame won't change when the frame size changes. You can tweak the scaling numerically in this pane if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Mac update as of April 2023.

1. Right (Command) click the image
2. Choose Content Properties
3. Then follow Ronan's example above